# To insert elements into the javascript input box

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I am a student studying JavaScript. I want to put the checkValue value in the strong tag into the input box, but I don't know how to write JavaScript to get it into the input box. Do I need to find cart_table of div? Or should I find a strong tag?

```
<script>
$().ready(function() {
   $("#optionSelect").change(function() {
       var checkValue = $("#optionSelect").val();
       var checkText = $("#optionSelect option:selected").text();
       var product = $("#productname").text();
       var price = parseInt($("#price").text());
       var test = parseInt($(this).find(':selected').data('price'));
       var hapgae = price + test

       if (checkValue != "no") {
           var whtml =
               "            <div class=\"cart_table\">\n" +
               "            <hr style='width: 300px; margin-bottom: 30px;'>" +
               "            <p style='font-size: 17px;'>" + product + "</p>" +
               "                <p style='font-size: 13px; margin-top: -10px; class=\"check\" margin-bottom: 20px;'>" + checkText + "</p>" +
               "                        <strong class=\"value_code2\">" + checkValue + "</strong>\n" +
               "                   <input name=\"value_code\" id=\"value_code\" class=\"value_code\">" +
```

Strong tags and input tags refer to this part.

```
               "                        <strong class=\"value_code2\">" + checkValue + "</strong>\n" +
               "                   <input name=\"value_code\" id=\"value_code\" class=\"value_code\">" +
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all i would recommend you to use backticks

```
var html = `
  <div>
    <span>Some HTML here ${some_var}</span>
  </div>
`;
```

this saves you time and effort, and you can then insert variable wherever you want

also check this thread

[Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you, but I just want to put the checkvalue in the input box.

Comment: what do you exactly mean? you want to render(show) input depending on if condition on checkvalue,
or you to put checkvalue variable in input

Comment: var checkText = $("#optionSelect option:selected").text();

I want to put this value in input name="value_code".

Comment: `               
 `<input name=${checkText}>`

`

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'm glad that you asked me about the purpose of the problem and tried to solve it.